# How to compose LIKE in T-SQL to show all rows except those containing ":","-","~"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filtering

I have a SQL Server engine in which I have a filed with filter clause. I need that clause to be compose to show all rows except those that contain **:**, **-**, **~**.

My query is:

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE '' LIKE '%[^:-~]%'
```

It is not working - it shows zero rows. Also I try this:

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE 'aa:a' LIKE '%[^:-~]%'
```

And it shows as result 1, which is not desired result.

Is there a way to manage this?

*REMARK:* expression after `like` must be string which will be saved inside the table field (for exmaple: `'%[^:-~]%'` will be used as `LIKE x.fldFilter`)

**EDIT:** I need to make validation inside my engine inside SQL Server. I have a table with Parameters. Inside it I have column `Format`. For a specific parameter I need to check if value provided fits `Format` column.

For example:

```
DECLARE @value AS VARCHAR(1000) = 'aaa:aa';

SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ParameterDefinitions X WHERE @value LIKE X.[Format];
```

Where `X.[Format]` column contains `'%[^:-~]%'`.

When I test a value check must return 1 if it fits conditions and nothing if not fits.

So if I test value `'aaa:aa'` or even `' '` it works. But when I have empty string (`''`) the condition does not working.

Unfortunately I can not change my engine and can not replace `''` with space for example. I just wonder why `''` does not fit the condition?

Comment: could you make a sample list of what is in your table and which rows you want returned

Comment: I updated my question @t-clausen.dk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to SQL Server not having a solid regex implementation.

Instead of negating your search with `^`

Negate it with Not

```
SELECT 1    
WHERE '' NOT LIKE '%[:-~]%'
```

Returns 1 row

```
SELECT 1 
WHERE 'aa:a' NOT LIKE '%[:-~]%'
```

Returns 0 rows

**EDIT:**
Breaking down your search cases

```
'' LIKE '%[^:-~]%'
```

`[^:-~]` requires a single character so an empty string must fail

```
'aa:a' LIKE '%[^:-~]%'
```

`%` is a 0 or more wildcard which lets `[^:-~]` take its choice of `'a'` while either `%` collects your forbidden character.

With a full regex engine we could repeat your negated range with the following `[^:-~]*` but SQL Server doesn't support that. [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

The only option left to us is to perform a search for the forbidden characters `'%[:-~]%'` and to negate the like.

Comment: I need the expression to be in single string - see my remark. I have engine in which I have filter expression in a table. I will need to apply it like: `LIKE tbl.fldFilter`. Inside `fldFilter` I need string expression like `'%[^:-~]%'`. So your answer (although correct) can not be applied to my problem.

Comment: So it does not work in any case, because of `%`, which gives me all characters?